# Verify correct port in javascript for wcf service

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, wcf, service

I have 10 different port number in for loop in my javascript, and wcf service is hosted on one of port number from listed 10 ports.

Is there any way i can check by using loop, on which port number my service responses just fine without any error in javascript using ajax json.

Here I have sample code but I want to check this for 10 diff port number:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $("#search").live("click", function ()
    {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost:55154/Services/Service.svc/GetCustomers');
        alert(link.port);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http://localhost:55154/Services/Service.svc/GetCustomers',
            data: '{"prefix": "' + $("#prefix").val() + '"}',
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response)
            {
                alert(response);
                //var customers = eval(response.d);
                //var html = "";
                //$.each(customers, function () {
                //    html += "<span>Name: " + this.Name + " Id: " + this.Id + "</span><br />";
                //});
                //$("#results").html(html == "" ? "No results" : html);
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert(a.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to do a loop and "pinging" the wcf service to detect where it is. I suggest to you to define a static wcf port number.

> Click in your WCF properties, after click in item menu "Web" and
>   configure a option "Apply server settings to all user (store in
>   project file)", so mark the option "Use Visual Studio Development
>   Server" and specific a port number.